# How to decrease space between paragraphs in python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

Am trying to decrease spacing between paragraph with the code below in `python-docx` but when apply the the formatting to the paragraph the last paragraph shrinks but the line between the paragraphs doesn't decrease.

i found some examples here [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449617/decreasing-the-vertical-space-when-using-the-paragraph-function-in-the-python-do) and [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48150222/changing-paragraph-formatting-in-python-docx/48160795)which but don't understand the `xml` part to achieve desired results.

I need your assistances to decrease the spacing between the paragraphs through python but not setting it via word file.

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE
from docx.shared import Pt


document = Document()

document.add_heading('THIS IS MY HEADER WANT TO UNDERLINE IT')


paragraph = document.add_paragraph('THIS IS MY FIRST PARAGRAPH ')
paragraph = document.add_paragraph('THIS IS SECOND PARAGRAPH')
paragraph = document.add_paragraph('SPACING BETWEEN EACH SHOULD BE DECREASED')

paragraph_format = paragraph.paragraph_format
paragraph_format.line_spacing = Pt(3)
paragraph_format.space_after = Pt(5)


print("document created")

document.save('demo.docx')
```

Answer (score 5):

If you check the generated Word file, you can see your code worked *precisely* the way you stated. That last paragraph – *the only one you apply your formatting to* – has a line spacing of 3pt and 5 pts of space after; all other paragraphs appear with default formatting.

So `python-docx` is working correctly, and if your output is wrong then it's because your code is wrong.

First off, I'd strongly advise not to set your line spacing to 3 pt; I assume you got confused because it 'didn't work' and you intended to set `space_before` instead. Secondly, make sure to apply your formatting to *all* paragraphs and not just that final one:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt

document = Document()

document.add_heading('THIS IS MY HEADER WANT TO UNDERLINE IT')

paragraph = document.add_paragraph('THIS IS MY FIRST PARAGRAPH ')
paragraph.paragraph_format.space_before = Pt(3)
paragraph.paragraph_format.space_after = Pt(5)

paragraph = document.add_paragraph('THIS IS SECOND PARAGRAPH')
paragraph.paragraph_format.space_before = Pt(3)
paragraph.paragraph_format.space_after = Pt(5)

paragraph = document.add_paragraph('SPACING BETWEEN EACH SHOULD BE DECREASED')
paragraph.paragraph_format.space_before = Pt(3)
# no need to set space_after because there is no text after this

print("document created")
document.save('demo.docx')
```

This results in a document with 3 pts of extra space before and 5 pts after (and with a regular leading) for all three text paragraphs.

Comment: how can i underline the heading

Comment: @OJOE: you do so by applying what you read in [the documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/text/underline.html). Is this a new question? I believe you got an answer for the current one here.

Comment: @OJOE note that `.line_spacing` is the space between the _lines_ of the paragraph, like "double-spaced" text common in drafts has a whole line-height of space in-between each line, in that case to allow editing marks. So if you have five lines in your paragraph, each of those five will get spread out more from each other and the paragraph will "expand" in height (or shrink if you set it lower). In contrast, space-before and space-after refers to the space between _paragraphs_, and I think is what you want.